# Jquery event on close class button in alert of Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to perform some Jquery Event on clicking the Close sign on the alert Block of Jquery.
My VIew code is as below::

```
<div class=' alert alert-block fade in'  >
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
    <p>Just Close Me  </p>
<div>
```

My Js code is as below::

```
$('button.close').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                alert("deleted list is"+id);

            });
```

As per the above code I am not able to detect or do Jquery events on clicking that 'X' button.

Comment: where is `data-id` attr ?

Comment: its given value by using knockout binding

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, you need to do this:

```
$('#my-alert').on('close.bs.alert', function () {
//code
});
```

Comment: addition to this answer. 'close.bs.alert' event happens before the element is removed. so if you're trying to do something after its gone (like resizing based on its absence), then use 'closed.bs.alert' instead. @AdRock answer demo's this

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old now but this is worth a look

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=alert-events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myAlert").bind('closed.bs.alert', function(){
        alert("Alert message box has been closed.");
    });
});  
</script>

<div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-info">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Note!</strong> Please read the comments carefully.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do a close, the dom element corresponding to the alert is removed from the Dom.

Try this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
<div id="messages" class="hide" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <div id="messages_content"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        $('#messages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show();
        $('#messages_content').html('<h4 class="usefont" style="text-align: center">Thank you message!</h4>');
        $('#modal').modal('show');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#messages').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
        $('#messages').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').addClass('hide').slideDown().show();
        e.preventDefault();

    });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you bind the close event

```
$('#my-alert').bind('close', function () {
    //do something…
})
```

PS. You should read the manual, everything is in it.

Comment: but from where you have taken this id attribute's  name?

Comment: but I have not given any ID as you can see in my code
and I don't have to give ID because the alert box is more than once

Comment: well then give one or use the class name

Comment: I am using the Bootstrap's close button therefore it is not performing any event on this